# Why i am getting this error keyword:Borough

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in Python.I merged two `columnsAfter` that i tried to change 'not assigned' value of a column with another column value. I cant do that. If I use `premodified dataframe` then I can change.

I scraped a table from a page then modifying the data in that dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
```

> pip install lxml

```
toronto_url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'

toronto_df1= pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]

toronto_df1.head()

toronto_df1.drop(toronto_df1.loc[toronto_df1['Borough']=="Not assigned"].index, inplace=True)

toronto_df2=toronto_df1.groupby(['Postcode','Borough'],sort=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))

toronto_df2.loc[toronto_df2['Neighbourhood'] == "Not assigned", 'Neighbourhood'] = toronto_df2['Borough']
```

This is the code i have used.

I expect to change the neighbourhood value with borough value.

I got this error.

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2656             try:
>   -> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Borough'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last) 9 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
>   get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2657                 return
>   self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
>   -> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2660
>   indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance) 
>   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
>   pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Borough'

Comment: Check is the column 'Borough' is present in your dataset exactly as you have written. Even an additional space at either end can result in a `KeyError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason of your `keyerror` is `Neighbourhood` is not column, but index level, solution is add `reset_index`:

```
toronto_df1= pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]

#boolean indexing        
toronto_df1 = toronto_df1.loc[toronto_df1['Borough']!="Not assigned"]
toronto_df2 = toronto_df1.groupby(['Postcode','Borough'],sort=False)['Neighbourhood'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
toronto_df2.loc[toronto_df2['Neighbourhood'] == "Not assigned", 'Neighbourhood'] = toronto_df2['Borough']
```

Or parameter `as_index=False` to `groupby`:

```
toronto_df1= pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M')[0]

#boolean indexing  
toronto_df1 = toronto_df1.loc[toronto_df1['Borough']!="Not assigned"]
toronto_df2=toronto_df1.groupby(['Postcode','Borough'],sort=False, as_index=False)['Neighbourhood'].agg(','.join)
toronto_df2.loc[toronto_df2['Neighbourhood'] == "Not assigned", 'Neighbourhood'] = toronto_df2['Borough']
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I already tried with reset index.But somehow it didn't work.But as_index=False worked.Thank you again.